# Prove that $a^2+b^2+16\ge ab+4a+4b$ for all $a, b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How to prove that for all numbers $a, b$,
>   $$a^2+b^2+16\geqslant ab+4a+4b .$$

I got an idea that I can move everything to the left side:
 $$a^2+b^2+16-ab-4a-4b\geqslant 0$$
and then treat it as a quadratic whose discriminant is probably zero yet there are two variables; how to proceed?

Answer (score 5):

From AM-GM you get the following inequalities,
$$\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)\geq ab$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(a^2+16)\geq 4a$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(b^2+16)\geq 4b$$
Now just sum them up

Alternatively you can use the result,
$$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca = \frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2+(c-b)^2+(a-c)^2)\geq 0$$
Substitute $c=4$

Comment: This is especially nice!

Answer (score 3):

$a^2+b^2+16-ab-4a-4b$

$=\frac{1}{2}\left[2a^2+2b^2+32-2ab-8a-8b\right]$

$=\frac{1}{2}\left[a^2-2ab+b^2+a^2-8a+16+b^2-8b+16\right]$

$=\frac{1}{2}\left[(a-b)^2+(a-4)^2+(b-4)^2\right]$

$\geq 0$

Equality occurs if $a=b=4$

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=(a,b,c)$ and $y = (b,c,a)$ and use [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality: $$|\langle x,y\rangle|\leq \|x\|\|y\|$$ then set $c = 4$.

In more detail, $$\langle x,y \rangle = ab + bc + ca,$$ $$\| x \| = \|y\| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$$ and finally, notice that $|r|\geq r$ for any real $r$ and thus we have $$ab + bc + ca \leq | ab + bc + ca | \leq a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Because of the symmetry in $a$ and $b$, we can eliminate the cross-term by changing variables via \begin{align}a &:= s - t\\b &:= s + t .\end{align}
Substituting and simplifying gives that $$a^2 - a b + b^2 - 4 a - 4 b + 16 = s^2 - 8 s + 16 + 3 t^2 = (s - 4)^2 + t^2,$$ but the lattermost expression is a sum of squares, so as desired the quantity is always nonnegative.

On the other hand, we can back-substitute to give a shorter (but less transparently motivated) solution: Rewriting gives
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{a^2 - a b + b^2 - 4 a - 4 b + 16 = \left(\frac{a + b}{2} - 4\right)^2 + 3 \left(\frac{a - b}{2}\right)^2 \geq 0}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a^2+b^2+16-ab-4a-4b=y$

$\iff a^2-a(b+4)+b^2-4b+16-y=0$

which is a Quadratic Equation in $a$

So, the discriminant  $(b+4)^2-4(b^2-4b+16-y)=4y-3(b-4)^2$ must be non-negative

$\implies y\ge\dfrac{3(b-4)^2}4\ge0$

The equality occurs if $b=4\implies a=4$